# Using rodbc to connect to SQL Server Databases on OS X - driver issues

Tags: sql-server, r, macos, rodbc

All,

I'm trying to configure rodbc (for R) on an OS X machine to connect to SQL Server databases.  This involves setting up at least a few components: RODBC itself, the DB driver, and the connection string.

There's a great walkthrough at http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/09/18/setup-odbc-for-r-on-os-x/ for setting up RODBC on an OS X machine and connecting to a local postgreSQL DB.  The last bit doesn't apply to my use case, though, as I still have driver issues with connecting to a SQL Server database.

Has anyone successfully set up RODBC to connect to a SQL Server database on an OS X machine?

Comment: I used the ODBC drivers from Actual Technologies and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks @joran.  I've seen those before but they look fairly pricey, especially considering the number of connections that I will need.  Do you happen to know of any free alternatives?

Comment: While using their drivers with SQL Server, I was never aware of any limitations on the number of connections, and I don't think that $35 is particularly pricey. Can you elaborate on what you think the limitations are on the number of connections and where you found that information?

Comment: @joran, I was particularly concerned with the 'max 5 connections' limitation.  Do you happen to know if that means max 5 _simultaneous_ connections?  I routinely connect to about 40 DB's, though probably no more than 5 at a time.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding any mention of such a limitation. Can you provide a link as a reference?

Comment: @joran Take a look here: https://www.actualtech.com/buynow.php under the different product names

Comment: I would assume thats 5 simultaneous connections.